# excerpt - don't use main content if empty

Tags: excerpt

trying to stop get_the_excerpt() from defaulting to the_content() if its empty.

this kinda works - well it seems to return 'xxx' so i think has_excerpt() isn't working?

```
function get_link_excerpt(){
    if(has_excerpt()){
        $LinkExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        return $LinkExcerpt."...";
    }
    return 'no excerpt'; 
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'get_link_excerpt');
```

what's the best way to control this?

best,Dc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress [sets up a default filter for `get_the_excerpt`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L146): `wp_trim_excerpt()`. It is this function that will [generate an excerpt from the content "if needed"](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1844). If you don't want this behavior, you can just unhook the filter:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse17478_init' );
function wpse17478_init()
{
    remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
}
```

Now `get_the_excerpt()` will just return the contents of the `post_excerpt` database field. If you want to return something when it is empty, you only need to check this case:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wpse17478_get_the_excerpt' );
function wpse17478_get_the_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    if ( '' == $excerpt ) {
        return 'No excerpt!';
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
```

There is no need to call `get_the_excerpt()` - it could even introduce an endless recursion because it applies your filter again!

Comment: Cheers again Jan! - that works. What are the numbers placed in these functions for? ie 17478

Comment: @daniel: To make sure they will be unique when someone copies and and pastes this code in their own installation, I prefix all function names with wpse (WordPress Stack Exchange) and the number of the question.